# Adding membership and authorization ASP.net MVC 4?

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Every tutorial I seem to be able to find on ASP.NET MVC via google is for MVC 3, and it doesn't run you how to actually do all of this work, it will tell you to rip files from the basic internet site template.

I have two problems with that...

A)I am using ASP.Net MVC 4, the files are different...
B)I want to know how to actually do this, copying and pasting will teach me nothing.

So, I would really like to know how to go about adding this functionality into a previously empty template. I have Razor in the project if that helps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> copying and pasting will teach me nothing

While that's true, running through the copy/pasted code in the debugger should teach you a lot.

Here is a really good article: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

In MVC4 and forward, ASP.NET will be using the newer SimpleMembershipProvider by default. So that might be your best bet as far as googling. The old SqlMembershipProvider is pretty nice but only works with SQL Server. Back in MVC3 they introduced the DefaultMembershipProvider, a.k.a. "Universal Providers". These use a very similar schema to the old providers, but got rid of all of the stored procedures and views so that you can use them with other databases (I believe any db supported by entity framework). The SimpleMembershipProvider is a new way to integrate authentication and authorization with possible 3rd party identity providers.

That said, you can use any of these 3 providers with an MVC4 project. Nothing about MVC4 pigeonholes you into a specific auth provider choice. But SimpleMembership seems to be the wave of the future, at least until things change again...

**Update**

Things did change again. In MVC5, there is now something called `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`.

Comment: I don't know about that.  Simple membership has a lot of limitations.  Maybe the future of trivial apps

Comment: @MystereMan, I was referring to the article content: "SimpleMembership: The future of membership for ASP.NET". I'm not endorsing simple, I actually prefer the ones in the System.Web.Providers namespace. Hopefully we can at least agree that the SQL ones have the most limitations of the 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing.  There are about 200000000000 different ways to do this, and you have to understand how authentication works under the covers in order to decide which method to use.

The best way to do that is to simply use the default template code, and then reverse how it works.  In other words, learn to crawl before you learn to sprint the 100 meter dash.

Mac 4 complicates matters because it uses a simplified membership system.  Why is simple more complicated?  Because its very different, while still trying to be compatible with the old way.

So use the default Internet template and study how it works.  That's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're confusing Authentication with Authorization.  You use Authentication to verify a requestor.  You use Authorization to deny or allow a resource to a requestor.

Forms Authentication hasn't changed since .Net 2.0.  The membership providers for doing the authentication has.  [danludwig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13433158/209259) pretty much sums up the new provider models (answers your question **A**), but using them (for the most part) is still the same.

MVC Authorization using the [AuthorziationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.authorizationattribute(v=vs.91).aspx) also has not changed for denying or allowing access to resources in MVC.

As for you question **B**, either you already know how to use Forms Authentication or you don't.  If you don't I'd recommend by starting with a [Walkthrough: Using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049(v=vs.98).aspx).